# Can't fix this one annoying error! :L

Tags: python, string, variables, typeerror

So, I'm a newcomer to Python.

We've started covering it in school and I'm having some issues.

I'm attempting to create a quiz in python with a points system. The points system works for the first two questions, but when it gets to the third question I always get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python33\ICT kat.py", line 63, in <module>
 print(" You have " + str(score) + " points so far!")
 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Below is the coding where the errors appears to be coming from:

```
 print("Question 3:")# This the third question in the quiz
 print(my_name + ", What is the total amount of days in February + March + June in a    leap year.")
 qu3_ans = input()# This is where the user would input their answer
 if qu3_ans == "90":# This is the answer to the question
 print("Good job! + 1 point")#If the user gives the correct answer this is displayed
 score = score + 1 #This is the points system

  else:
  print("That was the wrong answer! :(")#If the user gets anything other than 90 this  will be displayed
  print("No point for you! ^_^")# "  "

  print=(" ") #Used like the enter key in a word processing progra,

  print(" You have " + str(score) + " points so far!")#This is where the errors occurs,     and is used to displayed the current amount of points
```

Comment: Sounds like you've used `str` as a variable name somewhere else in the code.

Comment: You can change your last `print` statement to the following `print("you have ", score, " points so far!")`  that will fix it.

Comment: Also (since this is Python) make sure you're indenting your code correctly.

Comment: @Aya That should be an answer, I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you've used `str` as a variable somewhere, don't do that:

```
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> str = "foo"
>>> str(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-63-dd09b06c39ba>", line 1, in <module>
    str(1)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Instead of using string concatenation you can use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec):

```
print(" You have {} points so far!".format(score))
```